# Why 1 em = 1 pixel in this case?

Tags: html, css

isn't em suppose to be 16px by default? why in this case em = px?
shouldn't height of the image be 800px(16*50)?

```html
            <img id="header-img" width="50px" height="50em" src="https://nordvpn.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/favicon-196x196-1.png" alt="NordVPN Logo">
```

Comment: em is for font sizes. If none is set then 16px is typically the default. So 1em isn't necessarily a fixed size but relative to what has been set.  I would assume your image height would then be 50 * font size of the parent container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`px` is not allowed inside `width` attribute (same for `em`). In your case the browser will consider both your width and height equal to `50` which is `50px`

```html
<img id="header-img" width="50px" height="50em" src="https://nordvpn.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/favicon-196x196-1.png" alt="NordVPN Logo">
```

> width
>
> The intrinsic width of the image in pixels. **Must be an integer without a unit.** <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)</sup>

---

If you used CSS you will get the expected result:

```html
<img id="header-img" style="width:50px;height:50em" src="https://nordvpn.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/favicon-196x196-1.png" alt="NordVPN Logo">
```

Answer (score 0):

The height attribute specifies the height of an image, in pixels.

If you want to specify the height in 'em', you should use inline css

```
<img id="header-img" style="width:50px;height:50em;" src="https://nordvpn.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/favicon-196x196-1.png" alt="NordVPN Logo">
```